# Arduino error in code

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sketch, c

i'm making a project and i came across the follwing error.
Whan i'm trying to compile and upload the code i'm getting those errors:

```
ShiftRegisterTest1.ino:In function 'int* return_pins(int)'
displays.ino:9: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:9: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:12: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:12: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:15: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:15: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:18: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:18: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:21: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:21: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:24: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:24: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:27: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:27: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:30: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:30: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:33: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:33: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:36: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:36: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:39: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:39: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:42: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:42: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:45: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:45: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:48: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:48: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:51: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:51: error: expected `;' before '{' token
displays.ino:56: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
displays.ino:56: error: expected `;' before '{' token
Error compiling
```

I don't really understand why since the code (see below) should be working.

```
int * return_pins(int get_number)
{
static int rp[8];
switch(get_number)
{
            //DP, A, B, C, D, E, F, G
    case 48: //0
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};
        break;
    case 49: //1
        rp[8] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        break;
    case 50: //2
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1};
        break;
    case 51: //3
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};
        break;
    case 52: //4
        rp[8] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1};
        break;
    case 53: //5
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
        break;
    case 54: //6
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
        break;
    case 55: //7
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        break;
    case 56: //8
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        break;
    case 57: //9
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
        break;
    case 65: //A
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1};
        break;
    case 70: //F
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
        break;
    case 69: //E
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        break;
    case 80: //P
        rp[8] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
        break;
    case 72: //H
        rp[8] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0};
        break;
            //DP, A, B, C, D, E, F, G
    case 45: //-
    default:
    rp[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
    break;
}
return rp;
}
```

What this code does is to basicaly get an `int` ad input and based on this number it returns an `int array`. It's a very simple code which is called inside the `loop()` method which is located on an other file.

**Also i'm using Atmel Studio 6 instead of the original Arduino IDE but i dont think it has to do something with the problem :/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `fuenfundachtzig` said this cannot be done in this version of C++ Arduino uses. A replacement for this method is to set the number for each place.

For example:

```
case 48:
    //rp[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};
    rp[0] = 0;
    rp[1] = 1;
    rp[2] = 1;
    rp[3] = 1;
    rp[4] = 1;
    rp[5] = 1;
    rp[6] = 1;
    rp[7] = 0;  
    break;
```

This works the same however it takes more space but i dont this there is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you try here:

```
rp[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};
```

is only valid in C++11. (Before that you can initialize an array like this only upon initialization.)

Besides, as pointed out by Pete Becker, you need to declare `rp` as an array rather than a single `int`.

Comment: And what if i want to change the values of the array?

Comment: This isn't valid at all. `rp[8]` is an `int`.

Comment: Oh. And that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling without the "static" keyword. I think the compiler is complaining because it sees multiple statements trying to make an assignment to a static variable. Even if your logic is such that only one of the assignments will ever be executed the compiler doesn't know that.